# Java: How to structure or pattern a class so that we can map composed Object during Runtime?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, java-8, gson

Consuming a rest api which is returning json which has some fixed format and other change per endpoint. I am using gson library which maps incoming json to java classes.

So I have following abstract Resource:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AbstractResource {
    @SerializedName("Meta")
    @Expose
    private List<Meta> meta = null;
    @SerializedName("Body")
    @Expose
    private List<AbstractBody> body = null;
```

AbstractBody has following contents:

```
public class AbstractBody {
    @SerializedName("Body")
    @Expose
    private Computer computer = null;
    @SerializedName("Links")
    @Expose
    private List<Link> links = null;
```

AbstractResource is common for all endpoints but In Abstract body, It returns Computer in one endpoint and in other endpoint it returns Licenses and other Endpoint returns Clusters. All comes in Body field of json.So everytime AbstractBody gets changes.

Currently i have to make both classes again and again in different packages. So in main things goes like.

```
 ComputerResource agreement = gson.fromJson(json, ComputerResource .class);
```

I want to make common package for both abstractresoource and abstractbody and at run time it should decide which class it should get into.

How can i modify above structure to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `TypeToken`:

> Represents a generic type `T`. Subclassing TypeToken allows for type information to be preserved at runtime.

Let's assume we have two JSON structures:

```
{"meta": "value", "body": {"license": "true"}}
{"meta": "value", "body": {"computer": "true"}}
```

They are represented by a generic class `AbstractResource`

```
public class AbstractResource<T> {
    private String meta;
    private T body;
}
public class Computer {
    private boolean computer;
}
public class License {
    private boolean license;
}
```

When deserializing, `Gson` needs to be told how to deal with the generic body which can be supplied via `TypeToken`:

```
Type computer = new TypeToken<AbstractResource<Computer>>() {}.getType();
AbstractResource<Computer> resource = g.fromJson(json, computer);

Type license = new TypeToken<AbstractResource<License>>() {}.getType();
AbstractResource<License> resource = g.fromJson(json, license);
```

This allows for deserializing arbitrary nested structures into a generic field `body` of type `T`. It can be easily adapted to handling a list of nested structures via changing `body`s type to `List<T>`.

Comment: @Idz: Thanks for solution. I have checked this TypeToken is gson class. Is it possible to do something similar using jdk classes in place of third party classes?

Comment: The JDK does not provide JSON binding functionality, Gson and Jackson are commonly used. You could look into the Java API for JSON binding [JSON-B](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=367) and it's (currently) only reference implementation Yasson as an alternative, but this would introduce dependencies as well.